# ORDER BY in MySQL works fine with 1 column but not 2

Tags: mysql, database

I am looking to display the count and the occupation in order. I can do one just fine but when I add the second column to the ORDER BY statement is doens't work.

```
SELECT CONCAT("There are a total of ", COUNT(occupation), " ", occupation, "s.")
FROM occupations
GROUP BY occupation
ORDER BY COUNT(occupation) ASC, occupation ASC;
```

This is the result:

```
There are a total of 3 Doctors. 
There are a total of 4 Actors. 
There are a total of 4 Singers. 
There are a total of 7 Professors.
```

I tried reversing them and I also tried specifying the table name (occupations.occupation) to avoid any ambiguity but nothing works. Do I need to create separate variables?

Comment: What is wrong with your output? According to your order by, that looks to be doing exactly what it's supposed to be.. Count ascending then Occupation ascending... 3 , 4, 4, 7 is correct... and for the two 4 counts, `A` is before `S`

Comment: Please add an example of the desired result (indicating how it differs).

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads
I am looking to solve this puzzle

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a simple misunderstanding of the result of correct code. It is unlikely that Q&A will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any capital and small combinations in occupation then it will make it into one for all and then sort it. Definitely it will resolve the sorting issue.

```
SELECT CONCAT("There are a total of ", COUNT(occupation), " ", occupation, "s.")
FROM occupations
GROUP BY occupation
ORDER BY COUNT(occupation) ASC, initcap(occupation)  ASC;
```

Comment: How would this solve the issue?  An explanation would be useful.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The query I posted was correct - it turns out that the application was considering it wrong because the occupations were in uppercase instead of lowerca